# How would I structure a database for taking sales orders?

Tags: sql, node.js, database, postgresql, database-design

I am helping someone build a grocery deliver service. Very simple site and order process. The problem I am having is knowing how to come up with schema for the orders. The order would have contact information, but would also need to have all of the products they ordered. Since it can/will be different for each persons order, how would I go about designing this? Would I just have a products ordered field with a string list of all the items? Or would I need multiple linked tables?

Thanks!

Comment: The correct approach is to have a separate table for each entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need three tables:

a) Products - Contains the product details

b) Orders - Contains the order header, contact information etc

c) Product_Orders - is a table with two columns: product_id and order_id, that bind the orders to the products, and a quantity field and unit price.

You could have a customers table, but ideally information like the delivery address, etc, would be attached to the order so that if the user changes his address it will not affect your order history.

For the same reason unit price must be in Product_Orders, so that if a product price changes it does not affect previous orders.

Answer (score 1):

**Product table**
with name and price of all products.

**Customer table**
with name, address, phone etc...

**Order table**
with entries for each order: order id, cusomer id, date etc

**Order Items table**
with all ordered items, with link to id in ordertable, product table, quantity, price, etc...